# Separate one txt file to multiple txt files

Tags: python, text, data-processing

I have a text (.txt) file which contains

> ```
> cat1.jpg 386,575,538,734,0
> cat5.jpg 383,575,539,736,0
> dog16.jpg 382,576,538,735,0
> dog17.jpg 384,581,525,739,0
> .
> .
> .
> ```

I want to take the values in each row and get the names in the first column as the filename.

Example:

- cat1.txt, if open cat1.txt, there should be (cat1.jpg 386,575,538,734,0)
- cat5.txt, if open cat5.txt, there should be (cat5.jpg 383,575,539,736,0)
- dog16.txt....
- dog17.txt ...
- .
- .

I have used `man split` in Ubuntu, but it has created

command: `split -l 1 sample.txt`
output: xaa.txt, xab.txt, xac.txt and so on.

I just want cat1.txt, cat5.txt, dog16.txt, do17.txt and so on.

Could you help to solve this problem? (Python or MatLab.)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please modify this question to show what you have already tried, and the errors you are getting.  This sounds like a fairly simple problem but SO is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the name of your original .txt file is e.g. `pictures.txt`:

```
with open("pictures.txt") as picfile:
    for line in picfile:
        fullname, __ = line.split(maxsplit=1)
        name, __ = fullname.split(".")
        with open(name + ".txt", "w") as outfile:
            outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. It has created only cat1.jpg file and for others, without .txt and without content...

Comment: @pascaltx, I corrected my answer (and tested the code), now it works OK.

Comment: @pascaltx, try it again (copy/paste my code), it creates all files with .txt, I tested it.

Comment: MarianD, Many Thanks,

Comment: Many Thanks
It saved me a lot of time.
You are the best :)